# Write to specific part of preallocated file

Tags: ruby, file, file-io, seek

I am currently trying to write to different locations of a pre-allocated file.

I first allocated my file like so:

```
File.open("file", "wb") { |file| file.truncate(size) }
```

Size being the total size of the file.

Afterwards I receive data of XX size which fits into Y location of that file. Keep in mind this portion of the process is forked. Each fork has it's own unique socket and opens it's own unique file handle, writes to the file, then closes it as so.

```
data = socket.read(256)

File.open("file", "wb") do |output|
   output.seek(location * 256, IO::SEEK_SET)
   output.write(data)
end
```

This should in turn allow the forked processes to open a file handle, seek to the correct location (If location is 2 and data_size is 256, then the write location is 512 -> 768) and write the chunk of data that it received.

Although what this is doing is beyond my comprehension. I monitor the files size as it is being populated and it is bouncing around from different file sizes which should not be changing.

When analyzing the file with a hex editor, where the file data header should be at the top is filled with nullbytes (like wise with 1/4 of the file). Although if I limit the forked processes to only write 1 file chunk and then exit the writes are fine and at their proper location.

I have done some other testing such as dumping that part locations, and the start locations of the data and my equation for seeking to the correct location of the file seems to be correct as well.

Is there something I am missing here or is there another way to have multiple threads/processes open a file handle to a file, seek to a specific location, and then write a chunk of data?

I have also attempted to use FLOCK on the file, and it yields the same results, likewise with using the main process instead of forking.

---

I have tested the same application, but rather than opening/closing the file handle each time I need to write data in rapid succession (transferring close to 70mb/s), I created one file handle per forked process and kept it open. This fixed the problem resulting in a 1:1 duplication of the file with matching checksums.

*So the question is, why is opening/writing/closing file handles to a file in rapid succession causing this behavior?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your file mode.

```
File.open("file", "wb")
```

"wb" means "upon opening, truncate the file to zero length".

I suggest "r+b", which means "reading and writing, no truncation". Read more about available modes here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-c-new

BTW, "b" in those modes means "binary" (as opposed to default "t" (text))

Comment: Thanks, I thought "w" simply meant writing, and didn't know about its truncation properties. Also I purposefully used "b" since these are data files and not text files.